# Run multiple Promise.all() in Sequence (Reading the second Promise.all only after the first one is completed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I want to run multiple Promise.all functions in sequence where the second Promise.all starts only after the first Promise.all is returned. I tried to do it using async/await but I noticed that although the result of second Promise.all is displayed after the first one, it is actually running IN PARALLEL (which is not what I want).

In the example,

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'FirstBatch');
});

const promise4 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise5 = 42;
const promise6 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'SecondBatch');
});

async function asyncCall() {
let values1 = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
  console.log(values1);
  let values2 = await Promise.all([promise4, promise5, promise6]);
  console.log(values2);
}

asyncCall();
```

The output of the above code is:
Array [3, 42, "FirstBatch"]
Array [3, 42, "SecondBatch"]

The sequence is correct, but the problem is they are displayed at the same time (which implies that "SecondBatch" is NOT waiting for 2 seconds after the completion of "Firstbatch").

How do I make "SecondBatch" wait for 2 seconds after the completion of "Firstbatch"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2-second timeout starts executing the moment you create its promise (*). `Promise.all` doesn't "start" the promises, it merely ensures they are all resolved (or one of them failed) before it will resolve.

In order to make the sequence you desire, you have to create `promise6` after `values1` has been received.

```js
async function asyncCall() {
  const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
  const promise2 = 42;
  const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'FirstBatch');
  });
  let values1 = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
  console.log(values1);

  const promise4 = Promise.resolve(3);
  const promise5 = 42;
  const promise6 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'SecondBatch');
  });
  let values2 = await Promise.all([promise4, promise5, promise6]);
  console.log(values2);
}

asyncCall();
```

---

*) More precisely, the timeout is started by the function supplied to `new Promise`, which is executed synchronously during promise creation

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow-up question on this:
Suppose I want to print line called "asyncCall() completed" 

asyncCall();
console.log("AsyncCall Completed");

Is there a way to make the code WAIT until asyncCall completes before it prints
"AsyncCall Completed";

I know that I can do 'console.log("AsyncCall Completed")' at the very end of the asyncCall() function itself (to ensure it is run only after everything else has been completed) but I was wondering if there is another way too.

Comment: Every `async` function returns a promise. Thus, `await asyncCall(); console.log("completed")` and `asyncCall().then(() => console.log("completed"))` both work. (Note that many environments still don't support top-level `await`, so the first snippet might need to be wrapped in an async function — or IIFE)